# SwiftUI - Does adding a shadow mess up interactivity on TextFields?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a simple SwiftUI view for a Catalyst Mac app like so:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(envColor.getColor())
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("First", text: $envColor.stringR)
                    TextField("Second", text: $envColor.stringG)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)
            .background(Color.gray)

            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Right Side")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)

            Spacer()
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the App it just looks like this:
A simple view with 2 text boxes. Both of them you can freely type into without issue.

[image: App]

You can highlight and edit either 255 without issue.

However, when I add a shadow to my VStack like so:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(envColor.getColor())
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("First", text: $envColor.stringR)
                    TextField("Second", text: $envColor.stringG)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .shadow(radius: 5)

            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Right Side")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)

            Spacer()
        }

    }
}
```

The app looks exactly the same *but* I can't type in the `TextField`s at all. They don't highlight and I can't type in them. I looked at the Debug View Hierarchy and it looks fine with the `TextField`s in the front.

[Here's a video](https://youtu.be/o4hwAxnmCrI) of me using it with the shadow. As you can see the cursor doesn't change to let me edit.

Does adding a shadow to a VStack actually cause issue? And I doing something incorrect? Or is this a bug?

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine on my end. I am able to type and edit anything in textField, with and without shadow

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati I just added a video of what I'm seeing. I can't edit them when I add the shadow.

Comment: It is because UIKit is under the hood of SwiftUI. VStack just never call `drawRect` method so shadow will not work on it. Background with shadow works cause it makes additional `CALayer`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868344/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-uistackview/39720288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is a defect - you can submit feedback to Apple. Meanwhile I can propose solution - put shadow into background:

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

[image: demo]

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        TextField("First", text: $first)
        TextField("Second", text: $second)
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)
.background(Color.gray.shadow(radius: 5))    // << here !!
```

Comment: This worked for me. I found another solution to the problem that I put in another answer & I filed a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Just add clipped() and it will work:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField(
            placeholder,
            text: $text,
            onEditingChanged: {
                isEditing = $0
            }
        )
           ....
  }
    .background(Colors.shared.background.primary)
    .clipped()
    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 0, x: 0, y: 0.33)
    .padding(.bottom, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following change to my code solved the problem in addition to @Asperi's solution. I added `.clipped()` and now the `TextField`s work.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(envColor.getColor())
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("First", text: $envColor.stringR)
                    TextField("Second", text: $envColor.stringG)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)
            .clipped()
            .background(Color.gray)

            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Right Side")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 200)

            Spacer()
        }

    }
}
```