# Setting background color for customView has no effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, background-color

I have a `customView` which I display by after a `button-tap`. My problem is that setting `.backgroundColor` has no effect and it is just a `clear` background.

**CustomView:**

```
let wishWishView: WishStackView = {
    let v = WishStackView()
    v.backgroundColor = .cyan
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

**AddViewButton:**

```
@objc func addWishButtonTapped(){

    self.view.addSubview(self.wishWishView)
    wishWishView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    wishWishView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

`WishWishView` is just a simple `UIView` with a `StackView` inside of it.

Comment: apply background color to your view instead of stackView

Comment: That's what I am doing atm. `WishStackView` is a `UIView`, the name might be confusing but like I said in the question, it's a `StackView` within a `UIView`

Comment: Please add height and width anchor to your view.

Comment: thanks, that was actually another problem I wasn't even aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that it is a `UIStackView`, which does not support having a background color.

You can read more about why this happens, and possible workarounds here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868367/3992237

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Totally wrong, first you set your view like this:

```
let wishWishView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .cyan
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

now set your stackView, in my example I put in 2 label in vertical axis:

```
let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let label1 = UILabel()
    label1.text = "Label 1"
    label1.textColor = .red
    label1.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let label2 = UILabel()
    label2.text = "Label 2"
    label2.textColor = .black
    label2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let sV = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2])
    sV.axis = .vertical
    sV.distribution = .fillEqually
    sV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return sV
}()
```

after that set your button:

```
let buttonAddView: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Add View", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addWishButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

in viewDidLoad add button and set constraints

```
view.addSubview(buttonAddView)
    buttonAddView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    buttonAddView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    buttonAddView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    buttonAddView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
```

now write the function that add the view with stack view inside when the button is tapped with right constraints, in your function you call only the position of the view but not the size of it. Write your function like this:

```
@objc func addWishButtonTapped(){

    view.addSubview(self.wishWishView)
    wishWishView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    wishWishView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    wishWishView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    wishWishView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    wishWishView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishWishView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishWishView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishWishView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishWishView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

}
```

Now simply change background of the wishWishView to automatically set stackView background, and that's it...

Comment: thanks for the answer but what exactly are you trying to tell :D I have pretty much the exact same code. I just didn't post the code for my `WishStackView` and how I set it up because it is quite obvious.

Comment: youre right. Thanks, I couldve added the other `view-setup` .   I solved the problem with the help @Simon and @Nexus

Comment: Ok, have a nice day :)